# Keras + Tensorflow model.compile optimizer function

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using keras on a VM Ubuntu machine with a Tensorflow CPU backend.

I am messing around with the Keras Text generation example file , and I would like to be able to print the optimizer function I am currently using to compile my model:

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)
print(optimizer)
...
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

which prints as:

```
<keras.optimizers.Adam object at 0x7fdf2e406e48>
```

I would like this to print as:

```
# either:
Adam(lr=0.001)

# or:
Adam
0.001
```

my approach to this problem was this little bit of code:

```
optimizer = Adam
learning_rate = 0.001
optimize_funct = optimizer(lr=learning_rate)
print(str(optimizer))
print(str(learning_rate))
...
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimize_funct)
```

This operates correctly, but prints incorrectly:

```
<class 'keras.optimizers.Adam'>
0.001
```

Note: I'm very new and will likely require an elementary explanation of why this doesn't work, and of possible solutions.

Any help you can offer would be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `optimizer.__name__` instead:

```
print('{}(lr={})'.format(optimizer.__name__, learning_rate))
```